# How to use iTerm with QuickSilver

Tags: macos, quicksilver, iterm

I see a page dedicated to an iTerm plugin after googling "quicksilver iterm", but I can find no place to download it, and it doesn't appear to have built-in support. There's a section in preferences where you can change the terminal program, but it's greyed out and set on the default terminal.

Does anyone know how to make QuickSilver use iTerm instead of the default Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to go to the Plugins tab and find it in the list.

[image: Plugins Tab ->iTerm]

Comment: That is strange. I don't see that plugin.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: A reinstall fixed it.

Comment: I'm using B56a7, http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-alchemy/downloads/list  Glad you got it working.